# Can't delete document using imageReference in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React app where users upload images to Firebase storage and then the image URL is a field in the firestore document along with userID etc. When a user deletes an image, i want to remove both the stored image and the firestore document using the imageURL.

I am able to delete the Firebase storage image but not the document in Firestore.

I get a `n.indexOf is not a function` error when i try

```js
useEffect(() => {
    listAll(imageListRef.current).then((response) => {
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          setImageList((prev) => [...prev, url]);
        });
      });
    });
  }, []);

const onDelete = (e) => {
// id is the imageURL
    const { id } = e.target;
    console.log("Index: ", id);

//deletion in Storage which works
    const deleteRef = ref(storage, id);
    deleteObject(deleteRef)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Item was deleted from Firebase Storage", deleteRef);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        toast.error(error.message);
      });

//1. attempt to delete from firestore
    try {
      const imageDelete = collection(db, "images", where("imageURL", "==", id));
      imageDelete.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          doc.ref.delete();
        });
        console.log("Image should have been deleted from Firestore");
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }

2. attempt to delete from firestore
    try {
      const imageDelete = collection(db, "images", where("imageURL", "==", id));
      // deleteDoc(doc(imageDelete));
      imageDelete.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.ref);
        deleteDoc(doc.ref);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

return ({imageList.map((url, index) => {
            
           //render image with relevant HTML and onDelete when clicked
            
            }});
```

1. Structure of the data in Firestore.
2. Url from list all. Shown after clicking on image.
   [image: Firestore data]
   [image: url that i get when i click on an image]

These are solutions i found on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. I get the sense that some of the solutions are outdated.

How i upload the images to firestore:

```js
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, video);
          console.log("Upload Status: " + videoUploading);

          uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
              // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
              // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
              const progress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
              console.log(
                video.name + ": Upload is " + Math.ceil(progress) + "% done"
              );
              switch (snapshot.state) {
                case "paused":
                  console.log("Upload is paused");
                  break;
                case "running":
                  console.log("Upload is running");
                  break;
                default:
              }
            },
            (error) => {
              // Handle unsuccessful uploads
              toast.error(error.message);
              console.log(error.message);
            },
            () => {
              // Handle successful uploads on complete
              // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
              getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
                console.log(user);

                try {
                  addDoc(collection(db, "videos"), {
                    imageURL: downloadURL,
                    videoName: video.name,
                    createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
                    user: user,
                  });
                  toast.success(video.name + " has been uploaded");
                } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  toast.error(error.message);
                }
                resolve();
              });
            }
          );
```

[image: console logs]

Comment: It looks like your `id` value is the path of the image in the Cloud Storage bucket. Are you sure that is also the value you have stored in the `imageURL` in Firestore? The name of that field makes it sound like it's actuallyl a download URL, which would not match the path you have in `id`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, i've made edits to the question, this should answer your question.

Comment: can you show how you are adding  data to document in Firestore collection and also share console logs

Comment: @SathiAiswarya, i have added the edits to the question.

Comment: In your example you are using where inside collection try using inside query see this code [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/e9Y1nCjiLHmbHMeeryAg) and this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for reference

Comment: @Coolkid glad to hear that your issue is resolved, I have posted that as an answer. please check:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code you are using `where` function  inside collection  it should be inside query function.you can try the following code and also refer this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

```
try {
    const imageDelete = collection(db, "images");
    const q = query(imageDelete, where("imageURL", "==", id));
    const snaps = await getDocs(q); 
    snaps.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        deleteDoc(doc.ref);
        console.log("Image should have been deleted from Firestore");
    })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```